# Set field with content of associated objects on creation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the model:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    others = models.ManyToManyField(OtherClass, related_name='other_class', through='OtherClassRelation')
```

Now I need to create a `hash` based on `others`.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    self.hash = self.generate_hash()
    super(models.Model, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using)
```

But at the point of `save()` `others` is `None`.
I am creating the object using the admin-pages ...

On updating the object, it works.

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: when is "others" assigned? seems like you can't generate the hash until you have this info, which, in time is wrong bc your field does not accept nulls

Comment: @Alvaro "others" is assigned during the save process at the admin interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you use inlines to edit `MyClass.others` field in the admin.  If so then you can override [ModelAdmin.save_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) method to update `MyClass` instance after the saving of M2M inlines.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    ....
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        self.hash = self.generate_hash() if self.pk else 'NO-HASH-YET' 
        super(MyClass, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using)

class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        # save M2M with `through` attribute
        super(MyClassAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        # update `MyModel` instance to regenerate hash
        form.instance.save()
```